# How to add hyphen in string in SQL?

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a varchar data - `12345678`

I want to convert it to - `12-34-56-78`

How to achieve this in SQL?

I tried - `SELECT RTRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE('12345678', '(..)','\\1-'), '-')`

but it returns me  `\1-\1-\1-\1`

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Will it always be into a 8 digit number? Never shorter or longer?

Comment: I'm using Teradata, and the length can change.

Comment: [this article](https://teradataforum.com/teradata/20151005_143837.htm) should help.

Comment: '\1' and not '\\1'

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
SELECT RTRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE('12345678', '(..)','\1-'), '-')
```